# Length of substrings after ST_LineSubstring does not add up

Tags: postgresql, postgis, plpgsql

I am trying to find the indices of all points of a linestring that are within a geometry. In the beginning, I split the linestring into segments and check if they intersect with the geometry before iterating points. However, the splitting does not work as expected when splitting into ten parts. Their length does not sum up. The same occurs when I split the linestring into one segment:

```
raise notice 'Length %', ST_NumPoints(my_linestring);  --> 7350

my_substring := ST_LineSubstring(my_linestring, 0, 1); 
raise notice 'Length %', ST_NumPoints(my_substring);  --> 7323
```

How can I split the Linestring while preserving the same length and therefore keeping valid indices when iterating the points afterwards?

Comment: Please show the input.

Comment: Do you mean my_linestring? It is a LineString of consecutive GPS Points with srid 4326.

Comment: @Moritz it would be nice to see which function returns the wrong output. With a simple line I am not able to reproduce your issue. Can you try this? `WITH j (geom) AS (
  VALUES ('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-4.4719 54.3175,-4.4541 54.2598,-4.5351 54.2101,-4.5296 54.2678,-4.4541 54.2598,-4.4431 54.2173)'::geometry)
) SELECT ST_NPoints(geom), ST_NPoints(ST_LineSubstring(geom, 0, 1)) FROM j`

Comment: The query produces 6 on both columns as expected. So ST_LineSubstring somehow seems to have problems with larger linestrings.